# expo-av bare Error: Missing audio recording permissions

Tags: react-native, expo

Was looking to use the recently available expo packages for detached or "bare" apps in react-native.

Running into the following error:

Error: Missing audio recording permissions.

however I have already called the expo-permissions library to ensure RecordAudio permissions are obtained.

See https://github.com/Glorifundel/bareaudio for full example project

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Button title="Get Permission" onPress={this.onPressPermission} />
        <Button title="Record" onPress={this.onPressRecord} />
      </View>
    );
  }
  onPressPermission = async () => {
    const { status, expires, permissions } = await Permissions.askAsync(
      Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL,
      Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING
    );
    alert(`permission: ${status}`);
  };
  onPressRecord = async () => {
    const recording = new Audio.Recording();
    try {
      await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(
        Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_LOW_QUALITY
      );
      await recording.startAsync();
      alert(`onPressRecord recording!`);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(`onPressRecord error: ${error}`);
    }
  };
}
```

Pressing the "Get Permission" button reports an alert "permissions: granted", following that up with pressing the "Record" button results in an alert "onPressRecord error: Error: Missing audio recording permissions."

Any insight is appreciated,

Environment details:  I am running on windows 10, on an android emulator running android API 27 (8.1 Oreo).  Did a fresh Node v10.15.3 install as well as a fresh react-native-cli expo-cli install and generated the project with expo init --template bare-minimum.  followed up with yarn add expo-av and yarn add expo-permissions, followed the instructions found on the readme for the two packages.

Comment: Obtain the rights associated with the storage space. `Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL`

Comment: Added Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL as well, still being "granted" but error persists.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function startRecording() {
try {
  console.log('Requesting permissions..');
  await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync().then(() => {
    console.log('Permission granted!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
    allowsRecordingIOS: true,
    playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
  }); 
  console.log('Starting recording..');
  const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync(
     Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY
  );
  setRecording(recording);
  console.log('Recording started');
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
}
```

}